# How to search data in database using Django?

Tags: django, database, search

I have table in database which contain list of name with 2 or 3 words.
So I want that when user enter any string in input then that string will be split into Character wise then each character match with String in database.In atlast which string match more character of User string that result will be store in array according to character match.It also depend user input string pattern.

I'm giving you one example that I want

In table below name are stored

```
Neeraj Kumar
Pankaj Sharma
Rahul kapoor
```

User input string is:

```
rkp
```

then result will be as:

```
1.Rahul Kapoor
2.Neeraj Kumar
3.Pankaj Sharam
```

Reason:

```
Rahul kapoor has R,K and p which match all character with user string pattern
Pankaj Sharma has p,k,r which match all characters but its user string patter is wrong so it should be at after above name
Neeraj Kumar has r and k which match 2 and follow user string pattern
```

I want this search in Django framework with less code but anyway anyone can give code in any language.

I think this also helpful for others for make search better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [`iregex`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#iregex) to filter a QuerySet case independently, like this

```
Entry.objects.filter(name__iregex=r'[rkp]')
```

that would return all `Entry` objects that have a `name` with any (becaue `[]`) of the characters.

Then you can do the sorting in Python.

**EDIT:**

This should do it.

```
names = ['Neeraj Kumar', 'Pankaj Sharma', 'Rahul kapoor']
letters = 'rkp'

# All lower case to be case insensitive
data = [x.lower() for x in names]
chars = list('rkp'.lower())

# Result groups collectors
d1, d2, d3 = [], [], []

for item in data:
    # Find the places for all chars in the name
    indexes = [item.find(c) for c in chars if item.find(c) >= 0]

    if len(indexes) == len(chars):
        # All chars found
        if indexes == sorted(indexes):
            # Same order as chars
            d1.append(names[data.index(item)])
        else:
            # Different order
            d2.append(names[data.index(item)])

    elif len(indexes) > 0:
        # Not all, but some found
        d3.append(names[data.index(item)])

print(d1, d2, d3)
```

Comment: It gives better filtered data but order of data as same as they found in database with serial.How to change order of data that more characters match to input string.

Comment: I added a script to my answer that does the sorting.

Comment: I'm also adding script same as your script that give exact output that I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
names = ['Neeraj Kumar', 'Pankaj Sharma', 'Rahul kapoor']
letters = "rkp"
# All lower case to be case insensitive
data = [x.lower() for x in names]
chars = list(letters.lower())

# Result groups collectors
d1,x= [],[]
for item in data:
    indexes = [item.find(c) for c in chars if item.find(c) > 0]
    d1.append(len(indexes))
for i in range(len(names)):
    if max(d1) != 0:
        pos = d1.index(max(d1))
        x.append(names[pos])
        del d1[pos]
        del names[pos]
print(x)
```

This is better because when any list data is not match any character of input string that will not show and all match data are stored in single list with order of matching characters.